# Issue using intents on Android

Tags: android, android-intent, junction

I have an activity which behaves like this: 
A barcode scanner is called via an IntentIntegrator object, it reads an URI.
Then I want to pass the yielded URI into an object called JunctionInterface via its method connect().

```
private URI uri=null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    integrator.initiateScan();
    if(uri!=null) {
        JunctionInterface.connect(JunctionInterface.JX,this, uri);
    }
}
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
  IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
  if (scanResult != null) {
     try {
        uri=new URI(scanResult.getContents());
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
  }
}
```

When I debug I can see that the uri is clearly retrieved when calling uri=new URI(scanResult.getContents()). Unfortunately, JunctionInterface.connect() is not triggered.
Even worse, when I try to put something as simple as int i=0 after integrator.initiateScan() (which mainly uses activity.startActivityForResult(intentScan, REQUEST_CODE)), the application forces close.

What is the matter with this code ? Is there a way to fix it and make it behave like I want ?
Thanks.

Comment: please post logcat error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this also. I simply moved a part of your code in other place.

```
private URI uri=null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    integrator.initiateScan();
}
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
  IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
  if (scanResult != null) {
     try {
        uri=new URI(scanResult.getContents());
        if(uri!=null) {
            JunctionInterface.connect(JunctionInterface.JX,this, uri);
        }
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I was really close then... But I believe I cannot do anything after calling initiateScan() in onCreate ?

Comment: Sorry, did not understand your question ) Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: The application seems to block when I won't to do the following :
    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    integrator.initiateScan();
    /*some random code*/
    }
    public void onActivityResult...